# transition animation between two activity android

Tags: android, android-animation

I need animation like this image[image: this orange activity is old activity and white is new activity, I need animation with orange activity move left over white activity]

I want to create transition animation as per below requirement:
1) old screen move right to left.
2) New screen need to be appear as it is without any animation.
So while activity transist that time only old screen move but new screen need to appear without any alpha effect.

Currenly I have created similar animation but when activity transist it has alpha effect. but I dont want alpha animation.

Comment: so remove that alpha from the animation you have created

Comment: No if I remove the alpha then animation doesnot appear. because new activity come over(top) of old activity

Comment: then keep it as it is now